# Kafka-ui Timeout

Tags: apache-kafka, provectuslabs-kafka-ui

I installed Redpanda cluster and now I'm trying to install [kafka-ui](https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui) to manage it by GUI.

I have an ec2 instance on aws with 8GB ram.
In my test env (3 brokers) works fine, I can see my topics, Consumers, metrics, etc...

In my prod env (4 brokers) I can't see all info.
when I try to view Consumers or Metrics I receive the errors:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: Cancelled metadata request with correlation id 176225 due to node 3 being disconnected
2023-10-30 17:19:07,026 ERROR [parallel-2] o.s.b.a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler: [5fba5835-148]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/api/clusters/Redpanda-PROD/topics/mytopic/consumer-groups"
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Error listing groups on 10.0.100.40:9092 (id: 1 rack: null): Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listConsumerGroups
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.provectus.kafka.ui.controller.ConsumerGroupsController#getTopicConsumerGroups(String, String, ServerWebExchange) [DispatcherHandler]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ com.provectus.kafka.ui.config.CorsGlobalConfiguration$$Lambda$1004/0x00007fd6dc6746e0 [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ com.provectus.kafka.ui.config.CustomWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ com.provectus.kafka.ui.config.ReadOnlyModeFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/api/clusters/Redpanda-PROD/topics/mytopic/consumer-groups" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
```

this is my config file:

```
kafka:
  clusters:
    -
      name: "Redpanda-PROD"
      bootstrapServers: "10.0.100.40:9092"
      metrics:
        port: 9644
        type: PROMETHEUS
```

Do you have any idea how can fix it?

This is another error when I click on Consumer:

```
ERROR [reactor-http-epoll-1] o.s.w.s.a.HttpWebHandlerAdapter: [a12a6d65-1546] Error [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context does not have an entry for key [class io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer$Sample]] for HTTP GET "/", but ServerHttpResponse already committed (200 OK)
2023-10-31 00:07:21,587 ERROR [parallel-1] r.c.p.Operators: Operator called default onErrorDropped
reactor.netty.channel.AbortedException: Connection has been closed BEFORE send operation
        at reactor.netty.channel.AbortedException.beforeSend(AbortedException.java:59)
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.provectus.kafka.ui.controller.StaticController#getIndex(ServerWebExchange) [DispatcherHandler]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ com.provectus.kafka.ui.config.CorsGlobalConfiguration$$Lambda$994/0x0000000801621e00 [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ com.provectus.kafka.ui.config.CustomWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ com.provectus.kafka.ui.config.ReadOnlyModeFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
Original Stack Trace:
                at reactor.netty.channel.AbortedException.beforeSend(AbortedException.java:59)
                at reactor.netty.http.HttpOperations.then(HttpOperations.java:194)
                at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$OutboundThen.<init>(ReactorNetty.java:735)
                at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$OutboundThen.<init>(ReactorNetty.java:728)
                at reactor.netty.NettyOutbound.then(NettyOutbound.java:358)
                at reactor.netty.http.HttpOperations.send(HttpOperations.java:115)
                at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorServerHttpResponse.writeWithInternal(ReactorServerHttpResponse.java:93)
                at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.AbstractServerHttpResponse.lambda$writeWith$2(AbstractServerHttpResponse.java:190)
                at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.AbstractServerHttpResponse.doCommit(AbstractServerHttpResponse.java:266)
                at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.AbstractServerHttpResponse.lambda$writeWith$5(AbstractServerHttpResponse.java:187)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:291)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxContextWrite.java:101)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxContextWrite.java:101)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
                at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoInnerProducerBase.complete(Operators.java:2811)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onComplete(MonoSingle.java:180)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:152)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2547)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.doOnRequest(MonoSingle.java:103)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoInnerProducerBase.request(Operators.java:2878)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2341)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2215)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoSingle.java:115)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust.subscribe(FluxJust.java:68)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:200)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53)
                at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:292)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:293)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:474)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onSubscribe(MonoZip.java:466)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
                at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.request(MonoZip.java:216)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onSubscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:134)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:125)
                at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:189)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:121)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
                at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:258)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2305)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:338)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2341)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2215)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:164)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83)
                at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
                at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
                at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
                at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
                at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:155)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:503)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:122)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:258)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2305)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:338)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.request(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:98)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:437)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2341)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2215)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilter.java:85)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:471)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2025)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:164)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83)
                at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)
                at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
                at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:940)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:85)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2547)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2341)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2215)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:847)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:609)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:589)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:466)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:277)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:357)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:294)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83)
                at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2071)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:134)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:275)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1840)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.signalCached(MonoCacheTime.java:337)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onNext(MonoCacheTime.java:354)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(MonoPublishOn.java:181)
                at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
                at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

and I see a lot of this logs in the docker logs:

```
INFO  [kafka-admin-client-thread | kafka-ui-admin-1698745696-1] o.a.k.c.a.KafkaAdminClient: [AdminClient clientId=kafka-ui-admin-1698745696-1] Retrying to fetch metadata.
```

Comment: Where are you running the UI? In the same VPC? Double check your AWS VPC policies. Otherwise, make sure kafka `listeners` config is allowing remote connections. Also, MSK makes connection setup easier than your own EC2 cluster.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
My kafka brokers are distributed in 2 VPC in 2 regions (IE and UK) and kafka-ui is in the same VPC for the region.
The security group are ok, I suppose it goes to timeout because there are a lot of indo to load.
what is MSK?

Comment: Amazon MSK is a managed Kafka offering setup with best practices for running Kafka clusters with few button clicks and no further installation required. As mentioned, you'll also need to check your listeners config on your Kafka server.properties files, not only the VPC. Also, I recommend you test connectivity with standard Kafka CLI tools

Comment: Also, Redpanda has their own GUI https://docs.redpanda.com/current/reference/console/